# React reselect doesn’t work. There is no recalculation

Tags: reactjs, reselect

defaultState: {results: {}}
After api action results is populated, but reselect doesn’t recalculate result.

const selector = createSelector([selectors.getResults, selectors.getYear], (results, year) => ...);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the api action results in a completely new state object? If it just modifies the existing one, the caching kicks in, and you get previous results.

Comment: Yes, it modifies existing object (adds new object properties). How can fix recalculation in this case?